Understanding Conceptually How Python Curses Files Fit With Files Containing Functions
So i'm  building a command line script for installing gentoo and along the way decided i'd like to in as well beautify it or create a python curses menu alongside what functions i have handling processes for the actual installation.
I've built basic curses windows displays and menus, but my question is how do I generally fit the functions handling the underlying installation processes to the curses screen being refreshed and displayed?
For instance if I had a function that read input from a user into a dictionary on the non curses side of things would the input() method need to be replaced with getch() from curses? How do they fit together logically within either file?
It feels like i'm missing something integral about the process itself or that I might have to rewrite everything to fit.
I've tried wrapping functions in curses functions in order to gain menu functionality on the commandline however this seems like an oversimplification and doesnt really allow me access to full menu like system I believe.. i could be wrong though. Ive seen so many other project that simply have the curses file and a file list with functions yet have not been able to discern how exactly each programmer pieced them all together to form one program.

It's not easy to plug a UI into a non-UI process, especially with curses.  If you ever saw the original Linux install stuff, they just let the normal command line run until they needed input. Then, they brought up a quick curses-based UI to ask for input, then they went back to normal console stuff.  That's a good compromise.

If you're doing this in Python, you could use tkinter to provide a real GUI menu instead of curses. The non-GUI stuff will still use the regular terminal window.

To Barmar. i needed something that would work with only a barebones python3 install since it's gentoo related and thus i cannot install new software without compiling it first. like Tim Roberts states i guess i'll just go with a compromise.
